# JQuery - jquery .append() produces "Cannot read property 'nodeName' of null"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to make a table of listings. I have a variable that contains all the listings necessary called myListingsArray. I want to loop through the array, outputting 5 or less listings at a time. Each listing needs to have it's own properties. Here's what I have so far:

**HTML:**

```
<script type="text/template" id="listingsTemplate">
<div class-"listingsDiv">
    <h1 class="listingsTitle">My listings</h1>
    <table id="listingsTable">
        <tr>
            <th>Address</th>
            <th>MLS</th>
            <th>Broker</th>
            <th>Price</th>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
</script>
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#listingsLink").click(function(){
    var personalTotal = myListingsArray.length;
    $(".content").html("");
    var template = $("#listingsTemplate").html();
    $(".content").html(template);
    for(var i = 0; i < personalTotal; i++){
        appendListing(i, "#listingsTable");
    }
});
});

function appendListing(i, location){
/*$(location).append( "
    <tr>
        <td id=\"address\">" + myListingsArray[i].address + "</td>
        <td id=\"mls\">" + myListingsArray[i].mls + "</td>
        <td id=\"broker\">" + myListingsArray[i].broker + "</td>
        <td id=\"price\">" + myListingsArray[i].price + "</td>
    </tr>
");*/ //EDIT: EASIER EXAMPLE
  $(location).append(i);
}
```

When I run the code above, it returns an error saying 'Cannot read property "nodeName" of null'. "#listingsTable" clearly exists before the function is called so I don't understand why it throws an error.

Please help
Thank you

Comment: The quoted code is not valid JavaScript (you can't have unescaped line breaks in JavaScript strings). Please post a [mcve] with valid code replicating the issue.

Comment: Rather than creating the HTML as a string, I'd suggest just creating the objects and appending them as necessary. You can create a new table row and append cells to it by doing something like `var $tr = $("< tr/>"); var $td1 = $("<td id='address'").html(myListingsArray[i].address); $td1.appendTo($tr);` (then append `$tr` to your table at the end.) - A method like this is usually easier to manipulate, but better yet, you can achieve the line-separated syntax that you're evidently trying to achieve. [**I've created a brief example for you to check out.**](https://jsfiddle.net/7mj6dfun/)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I took a little break, came back, ran my code again and it suddenly worked. I refreshed it a thousand times before and it didn't but for some reason now it does. Sorry to bother, have a good day everyone!